# How I change the modal of adding address at checkout magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

[image]

Currently the modal that I want to change is as in the image.
And where Line 1, Line 2 etc. is written, this is where I want to change, but this modal is done through the knockout and I can't find a way to change these labels and make the fields mandatory, how can I do that?